# Complex configurable products

Tags: magento, magento-1.6

Here is the scenario. I have a configurable product which has two attributes. However, the price increment for the second attribute is dependent on the first. The price increments are a combination of fixed and percentage. So, lets assume the two attributes in question are size and colour - the amount added on for larger sizes is fixed, but the amount added on for different colours is a percentage.

The issue is that magento is adding the percentage increment for colour to the base price, not to the price plus the fixed increment for size.

As an example, let assume my product is available in three sizes, small medium and large; and in three colours, red, green and blue. The increment for medium and large are £5 and £10 respectively, and the increment for colour is 5% for green and 10% for blue (to be applied dependent on the size selected). My product has a base price of £100.

A customer purchasing a medium red product would pay £105, however magento applies the same price to a customer purchasing a medium blue product (because the percentage increase is calculated BEFORE the size is selected).

Is there any way to handle this so that the correct percentage increase is calculated AFTER the size is selected?

Cheers

Simon

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally I do not like to recommend this extension as it makes pricing in Magneto way more complicated and time consuming (I just got out of it myself and it was not the fault of the module), but I think this might be the solution for you:

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/simple-configurable-products.html

Basically this modifies the way Configurable products are priced so that it uses the price of the simple product and not the values contained in the super attributes.

The upside is that the price of the simple product is the price that it will be sold for on the configurable page.

The downside is that it is very easy to have the website do some funky things with pricing if you are not careful. For example we had a lot of scenarios where the configurable product price was $10.00, but all the simple products price was $8. Each item in the dropdown had a "negative upcharge" in there.

This was not the modules fault, rather carelessness of people managing the products.

Comment: Many thanks Josh, this does the job perfectly. Couple of warnings to anyone else thinking of using this tho. Firstly, heed Josh's warnings above about the potential for pricing screwups. Secondly, it fundamentally changes the way ALL configurable products in your catalog work. So, when I install this I will have to revisit all the configurable products in my catalog (about 2,000 including variants) and update the pricing. However, it also has some nice additional features like dynamically changing the product photo to show the selected configuration. Nice extension for a freebie. Cheers!

Comment: When you implement this extension, I would modify the pricing BEFORE you install the extension. That way you wont have to deal with pricing oddities when you implement.